# Can it be OK to derive from a standard library type while also violating the Liskov principle?

Tags: c++, inheritance, liskov-substitution

I would like to define a shared pointer whose `operator==` compares the pointed to values instead of the pointers, something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct deref_shared_ptr: std::shared_ptr<T> {
    bool operator==(const deref_shared_ptr rhs) const { 
        return (**this == *rhs);
    }
};
```

This type has two potential problems:

- It derives from a standard library type.
- It violates the Liskov substitution principle, since it changes the semantics of `operator==`.

However, I am thinking that neither of the two is a problem unless one uses the base type pointer/reference to refer to the derived type. In particular, these problems might never occur in template code. For shared pointers the situation is even better: shared pointers are stored and passed by value.

Is my logic correct? Are there still good reasons to avoid the above definition in favor of composition?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I won't say your logic is definitively wrong, but it gives me a queasy feeling -- e.g. what happens if someone accidentally uses it as a `shared_ptr` anyway?

In this sort of situation I make my own class that *contains* the `shared_ptr`.  E.g.

```
class CustomPtr {
    shared_ptr<XType> m_xp;
public:
    ... some stuff ....
    operator bool()const{return (bool)m_xp;}
    void reset() {m_xp.reset();}

    Transport *operator->(){return m_xp.get();}
    const Transport *operator->()const{return m_xp.get();}
    ... more stuff ....
};
```

I have to proxy or otherwise wrap any interface that I want to use -- but I consider this an advantage.  I generally only use a handful of access methods, and I like to be confident that no-one is using unexpected methods.

Comment: Private inheritance combined with using to make selected members visible has the same effect.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Which requires a large series of `using` statements.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It (potentially) does, but there are still a couple of advantages. First, it's half (or so) the syntactic overhead, and second, even a compiler that sets new records for lousy optimization *still* isn't going to turn a `using` declaration into an extra level of function calls.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Yeah I know, but it's annoying that there's no simple way to say, "I want to inherit from this class and expose everything it does... except nobody outside this class can cast me back to the base class." The fact that you have to list every method you want to inherit individually is a huge annoyance.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yup, no argument from me on that. It'd also be nice (at times) to be able to say (in essence) `using everything but x, y, z;`

Comment: @NicolBolas It requires at most as many using statements as there are forwarding function required. Agreed that it would be nice to say `using everything but x, y, z;` to shorten the list.

Comment: @Sjoerd How would you implement `make_shared` for the privately derived shared pointer? Would you use a re-interpret cast on`std::make_shared`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning First of all, I wouldn't call it `std::make_shared` as it isn't a shared pointer - it's a derefed shared pointer. So it should be named differently, e.g. `foo::make_deref_shared` or `foo::MakeCustomPtr`. To answer your question: declare this template a friend, so it has full knowledge of the private inheritance, and no casts will be needed. (Exact details are left as an exercise to the reader)

Comment: @NicolBolas As opposed to this way, which requires a large series of function wrappers, which are far more error-prone than `using` statements.

Comment: @immibis, @NicolBolas, @Sjoerd I agree that private inheritance and `using` are a good way to do this.  Someone should post such an example as an answer (I'm not confident I could get it right quickly) .  But I see having to explicitly write a (preferably short!) list of the `using`s  as a *feature* rather than a bug.  It's good to restrict the interface to an auditable subset.